# How can i override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml

I have created a custom module in magento 2 and its layout file is located in

```
app/code/Learning/RewriteSales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

but the system loads the layout from

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

instead of my custom layout file.

How can i override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file?

the complete code of sales_order_view.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Learning_RewriteSales::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
        <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="order_item">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Learning_RewriteSales::order/view/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
        <arguments>
             <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Producthhhh</item>
                     <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                            <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                            <item name="image" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="order_item">
        <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" name="sales_order_view_items_renderer_defaultrenderer" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml" />
        <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                            <item name="image" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-image</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

but the module does not take this layout.

Comment: Add your complete code of RewriteSales module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside **module.xml** file,
you have to declare dependency of core module,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

You have override your xml file at right place,

```
app/code/Learning/RewriteSales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

Inside your file, you have to just keep only required code to work your custom layout file inside body tag of xml file.

Demo for set different template file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>       
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::mycustomfile.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>

</page>
```

You have to first check if any log error are generated for this layout.

**You have to just clear cache and remove var folder.**

Comment: no log error was generated

Comment: **the layout is taken from vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

Comment: i have updated my answer. please check

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya - can you plz check this question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191243/how-to-add-custom-section-in-admin-create-invoice-magento2

Answer (score 5):

if you are overriding layout xml of any core module you should mention sequence in module.xml like this :

```
<module name="vendorname_modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```