# Magento 2.2.4 Overriding vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, xml

I am trying to hide the Store View change option by overriding vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml and commenting out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_new"/>
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setTitleClass">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">complex</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!--
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
                <action method="setUseConfirm">
                    <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer> -->
    </body>
</page>
```

It works if I comment this section directly from the vendor module. But, since it is not a good practice I tried to override it via following this instructions: [How can i override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140626/how-can-i-override-this-vendor-layout-file-with-my-custom-layout-file-in-magento/140635#140635)

but it is not working for me. Please help.

**UPDATE**

There is the custom module I created:

**registration.php**

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_CatalogProduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc>module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_CatalogProduct" setup_version="1.0">
    <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>

        </module>
</config>
```

**view>adminhtml>layout>catalog_product_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_new"/>
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setTitleClass">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">complex</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!--
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
                <action method="setUseConfirm">
                    <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer> -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: @Korbin This is adminhtml area file you cannot override in frontend..@ishu did you run upgrde and content deploy command

Comment: Yes I have run all the command..I also tried to override by creating an adminhtml theme..but it won't work. Any other idea how I can hide that option from product edit page?

Comment: try to place "view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml" file in your custom module.

Comment: Yes I have tried that..please see my updated question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this, you can simply create 1 xml file with below code in your custom module.

> view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Using this, you can achieve your desired result.

Comment: worked like a charm...thank you so much.!

Answer (score 1):

Copy that file and place it in custom module:
`app/code/<vendor>/<module>/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml`

and do not forget to add sequence in `etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CutstomModule" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Please see my updated question..thank you @Ronak Chauhan

Comment: this should work. remove unnecessary code from layout file.

Comment: ..don't know why not able to tag properly.. Removed the unnecessary code also took suggestion from above. Working nicely. Thank you

Comment: please accept the answer if it works for you, so it can help others also.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this..how to accept the answer?

Comment: you can accept only one answer that you already did. so no need to accept 2 answers.  happy that your problem resolved.

Comment: Okay got it..thank u!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Comment the code on the overided file, It won't work, You can use below code to remove the container

```
<referenceContainer name="page.main.actions" remove="true" />
```

Comment: thank you.! it is working now.!

Comment: You are welcome...